# Orden de datos tabla mysql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Al ingresar datos a esta tabla con el **id**  auto_increment, 
empieza en orden desde el  1  cunado llega al 3 se desordena luego el  4  lo pone bien el  5  también  llega al  6  y se desordena la idea no es organizar con un **order by**  si no que automáticamente estén en orden me pueden explicar a que se debe esto y como solucionarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas ordenando de forma descendente por la columna `name`.  Simplemente has click en la columna `id`.

Comment: Hola oye no al volver a cargar la tabla sigue igual y en mi aplicación también los muestra en desorden solo que yo he intentado haciendo order by

Comment: hasta eliminado todos los datos los ingreso otra vez y quedan así en desorden

Comment: Deberias agregar el query que estas usando con `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las bases de datos no ordenan los datos a menos que uses una clausula `order by`.

Es importante que entiendas como funciona un motor de base de datos. Al pedirle datos con una consulta del tipo

```
Select *
from tabla
```

el motor de base de datos devuelve los registros a medida que los va encontrando en sus posiciones en el disco. Ningun motor asegura ningun orden a menos que se le diga especificamente con una clausula `order by` de que forma se deben mostrar los registros.

Es importante entender este concepto, ya que para la base de datos, los datos son solamente datos sin orden.